# Trying to automate logic process by selenium on osx/safari. But getting constant error

Tags: python, macos, selenium, safari

I am trying selenium to login to some site but I am getting constant error.

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Could not create a session: You must enable the 'Allow Remote Automation' option in Safari's Develop menu to control Safari via WebDriver.

I have already enabled remote automation from browser. Below is the code used.

```
from selenium import webdriver

#Following are optional required
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

    baseurl = "xxxxx"
    username = "xxxx"
    password = "xxxx"

    xpaths = { 'usernameTxtBox' : "//*[@id='user_login']",
               'passwordTxtBox' : "//*[@id='user_pass']",
               'submitButton' :   "//*[@id='wp-submit']"
             }

    mydriver = webdriver.Safari()
    mydriver.get(baseurl)
    mydriver.maximize_window()

    #Clear Username TextBox if already allowed "Remember Me" 
    mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['usernameTxtBox']).clear()

    #Write Username in Username TextBox
    mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['usernameTxtBox']).send_keys(username)

    #Clear Password TextBox if already allowed "Remember Me" 
    mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['passwordTxtBox']).clear()

    #Write Password in password TextBox
    mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['passwordTxtBox']).send_keys(password)

    #Click Login button
    mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitButton']).click()
```

Comment: Try to kill all the Safari driver instances via Task Manager.

Comment: Thanks for such great suggestion. It worked @Guy